# React Body Css with Bootstrap 4.5.2

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm not an expert in React JS infact im training on it but i want to understand this below concept:

upon adding boostrap 4.5.2 to my React Js the project inhreted css main body classes, i'm trying to understand why it's inhereted and can't be changed in the source ?, for exmemple i wanted to chaneg the main body background css and i m not able to find the source fine to change it ( check below screenshot )

[image]

i even tryed to changein the bootstrap.css file i imported into the project but also it's not changing, the only why to do change the background color is to create an new css file import it in the index.js and in the file force the background css color with the !important tag,

my question is why/where can't change the source file and how to find it if iwas wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React App, you can usually modify the `<body>` inside the `App.css`.

```
body {
  background-color: #000
}
```

Comment: app was created with npx creat react app so there was no app.css but instead index.css which  is ignored because of the bootstrap